# unable to start service from activity using startService

Tags: android

all tutorials tell me to do this:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

but there is no constructor that takes Activity, Class and so i get syntax errors

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

I am attempting to spawn a service this way,

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
```

but my service never executes.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {                                                                                                                                                                     

    public MyService() {                                                                                                                                                                                           
        super("MyService");                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {                                                                                                                                                                     
        //do stuff                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

}
```

how can i spawn a service?

ANSWER: my android manifest didnt specifcy package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actual problem (as found in comments) added here :**

The service was in a different package, so in the manifest it has to be fully qualified, e.g. `<service android:name="actual.package.of.MyService"/>`

**Old Answer:**

1. If you try to launch the service in an inner class, you should not write:

   ```
   startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
   ```

   But:

   ```
   startService(new Intent(ActivityName.this, MyService.class));
   ```
2. Make sure your service appears in the manifest.
3. Add a debug print inside the `onHandleIntent` to see whether it starts or not.

Comment: ...
<service android:name=".MyService"/>
    </application> in my manifest, and now i'm starting it using the 2nd line, i know the line before startService is being called because i'm logging it, but nothing within intentHandler is called

Comment: #1, Activity is a subclass of Context, so you can use it when creating intent, #2 manifest seems OK, #3 have you tried printing something in the onHandleIntent?

Comment: first line of onHandleIntent is a log command to see if it ran.

Comment: Are the Activity and the Service in different packages?

Comment: OK, change in the manifest to: `<service android:name="actual.package.of.MyService"/> `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10803/discussion-between-binyamin-sharet-and-tipu)

Answer (score 0):

Services are not something visible

Possibly you have not declared the service in manifest file.

I dont think there is any problem with the code.
Override onstartCommand and oncreate method and just put a log statement and check logcat